# Getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException for datasources in IBM Websphere server while starting application

Tags: spring, websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

I am getting  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException for datasources while starting IBM Websphere server.Can you let me know why I am getting this error.

Error:

```
2017-04-24 19:25:04,220 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'befRetailItemName' defined in class path resource [SpringContextFiles/range-RetailItemNameContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'befRetailItemNameDb' while setting bean property 'dbBef'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'befRetailItemNameDb' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/rixrangedomainmodel-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/ikea/rix/range/bef/impl/BefRetailItemNameImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@com.ikea.rix.common.annotation.Rix01DataSource()}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@com.ikea.rix.common.annotation.Rix01DataSource()}  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,224 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EBCRIX01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/DS-ref: First component in name DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,239 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IMPCRC01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/IMPCRC01DS-ref: First component in name IMPCRC01DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,249 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CRCCEM01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/CRCCEM01DS-ref: First component in name CRCCEM01DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,260 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SCPIXCEM01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/SCPIXCEM01DS-ref: First component in name SCPIXCEM01DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,277 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EBCRIX01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/DS-ref: First component in name DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,289 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IMPCRC01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/IMPCRC01DS-ref: First component in name IMPCRC01DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,301 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CRCCEM01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/CRCCEM01DS-ref: First component in name CRCCEM01DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]  
2017-04-24 19:25:04,316 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SCPIXCEM01DS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/PUBLIC_PTE_3/ebcrix01-1.41.0.ear/ebcrix01EbcFwkWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ebc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: PUBLIC_PTE_3/nodes/ptseelm-lx4637.ikeadt.com/servers/ebcrix01_srv, name: jdbc/SCPIXCEM01DS-ref: First component in name SCPIXCEM01DS-ref not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

Comment: The path in the messages indicates an application installed into the traditional WAS runtime and not the Liberty one. If running in Liberty my best guess would be you don't have the JDBC resources defined in server.xml.

Comment: when I tried to start application in WAS server I am getting the above error.